# Error when creating waffle chart - object cannot be coerced

Tags: r, waffle-chart

Attempting to make a simple `waffle` chart with the below vector `pie`:

```
  rideable_type number_of_trips
  <ord>                   <dbl>
1 Classic                    58
2 Electric                   36
3 Docked                      6
```

The function I am using is:

`waffle(pie, rows=6)`

This function returns the following error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I'm sure that error is because `rideable_type` is `characters`, because when I run:

`waffle(pie$number_of_trips, rows=6)`

It runs just fine, but the legend names are `A`, `B`, `C`. I just want the the legend to correspond to the `rideable_type`. I'm sure I could do that manually...but it seems unnecessary. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument needs to be a named vector, so you can do:

```r
waffle(setNames(df$number_of_trips, df$rideable_type), rows = 6)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I figured out I can use `setNames` to solve the problem:

```
pie <- setNames(pie$number_of_trips, c('Classic','Electric','Docked'))
waffle(pie, rows=5, legend_pos='bottom')
```

Produces what I need:

[image]

I realized that `waffle` thought my vector was unnamed. I believed the function would automatically use the first column. Still not sure `waffle` doesn't, but this solved my question.